# Normal distribution as an approximation to the binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

Two fair dice are tossed. 
a) Find the probability of obtaining 22 times the total score of 7 if these two fair dice are tossed a total of 120 times.
b) Determine the number of tosses needed if the probability of obtaining the score of $7$ at least one is $0.85$ or more.

The probability of obtaining a total score of $7$ is $1/6$.

$X\approx B(120, 1/6)$

$mean= 20$

$Standard deviation=4.08$

I have find out for a. But cannot solve for b.

The answer given for b is $11$.